# Unity FirebaseAuth by phone, VerifyPhoneNumber

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

My Unity project use FirebaseAuth to sign-in by phone number. When I use method VerifyPhoneNumber, it always return error: Unable to verify the given phone number.

I tried many time with test phone number.
I expect the app will run into one of 2 method: verificationCompleted, codeSent.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: thanks, I found the bug. The method VerifyPhoneNumber has param autoVerifyTimeOutMs only in range 0-120 seconds. I set param autoVerifyTimeOutMs too high. I found error when saw android log of debug build.